# While deleting the object from realm db, Getting error as reason: 'Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.'

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, codable, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to delete the realm object using index path ,Getting error as 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.'

1. declare the array of MainModelClass and realm

   ```
   var arrSavedData = [MainModelClass]()
   var realm : Realm?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.getDatafromrealm()
     realm = try! Realm()
    }
   ```
2. function written to get data from realm database`

   ```
    func getDatafromrealm() {
      realm?.beginWrite()
      let data = realm?.objects(MainModelClass.self)
      let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      do{

        let result = try decoder.decode([MainModelClass].self, from: jsonData)
        for i in 0..<result.count {
            arrSavedData.append(result[i])
        }
        self.tblSaveData.reloadData()
      }
    catch let error as NSError{
        // error.description
        print(error.description)
      }
       try! realm?.commitWrite()
    }
   ```

3.tableview method to delete the realm object using the indexpath

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
       UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if editingStyle == .delete {
        realm?.beginWrite()
        realm?.delete(arrSavedData[indexPath.row])
        try! realm?.commitWrite()
        self.tblSaveData.reloadData()
        
    }
}
```

4.and last my MainModelClass

```
class MainModelClass : Object,Codable {

   @objc dynamic var title:String?
   @objc dynamic var link: String?
   @objc dynamic var author: String?
   @objc dynamic var thumbnail: String?
   @objc dynamic var itemDescription: String?
   @objc dynamic var content:String?
   @objc dynamic var pubDate:String?

}
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague; you have a mysterious `realm?` being used but no indication where it came from or what it contains. Also, the error is pretty accurate - an object created on a Realm can only be deleted on that realm. So this is probably a threading issue - update the question with further details. It's also a little odd that Realm objects are being read from realm, encoded *into* JSON and then immediately decoded *from* JSON and added to the tableView datasource. Why not just use the Realm objects as the datasource?

Comment: updated the code @Jay.Actually I am new at realm and that 's why I have not used Realm objects as the datasource concept.

Comment: This is still unclear; Why read in Realm objects, encode them, decode them and put them into an array? That's a lot of extra work and those objects are now disconnected and no longer live updating. You should read in the realm objects and use the resulting Results object as your dataSource; `var resultsDataSource: Results<MainModelClass>? = nil` and then populate the datasource in viewDidLoad `self.resultsDataSource = realm.objects(MainModelClass.self)` - then use that dataSource to back your tableView. To be notified of changes, add an observer to the Realm Results object.